# Make an Indexed Array of <li>'s

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a typical navigation set up in my html, like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Etc</li>
</ul>
```

I want to create an indexed array of the `<li>`'s, then `.addClass` to any `<li>` whose index # is greater than a specified number.

What is the best way to do this?

I apologize for the sparse information, but I'm not really sure how to approach it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('#navigation > li:gt(42)').addClass('greater-than-the-answer');
```

Have a look at the [selector API docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: I did not know there was a selector for that. Didn't know it would be that simple! Thanks Matt.

Comment: @Rrryyyaaannn there's a selector for everything, just memorize the API

Comment: I see what you mean. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
var spec_number = 3;
$('#navigation').children().each(function(index, item){
    if(index > spec_number) $(item).addClass('indexGreat');
})
```

Comment: ... or use the existing selector syntax.

Comment: @Tomalak -- that is true as well. i had a bit of a brain freeze when answering the question

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you want to add the class to items with index > 42, you can [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) the collection and add the class to all items that pass from the filter:

```
$("#navigation li")
    .filter(function(index) { return index > 42; })
    .addClass("myClass");
```

Comment: ... or use the existing selector syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#navigation li').each(function(){
    if($(this).index() > 2)
    {
        $(this).addClass('whatever');
    }
});
```

Comment: ... or use the existing selector syntax.